# Why isn't the growth of $\mathrm {Iso}(\mathbb R ^2)$ sub-exponential?

Tags: group-theory, subgroup-growth

Given a finite subset $S$ of a group, denote by $\gamma_S(n)$ the number of distinct elements that are words of length $n$ in $S\cup S^{-1}$.

A group is of **sub-exponential growth** if for every finite subset $S$, the number $\gamma_S(n)$ satisfies $\sqrt[n]{\gamma_S(n)} \to 1$.

I have proved the false claim that the isometries of the plane are a group of sub-exponential growth.

This must be false, because a group of sub-exponential growth does not admit a paradox, while the group of isometries of the plane does admit a paraox. (
The Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz paradox.)

Which of the following parts is my mistake?

1. A semidirect product of two groups of sub-exponential growth is again sub-exponential.

(Proof: if $G=H \rtimes Q$, take a word $h_1q_1h_2q_2\ldots $ and make it into a word of the form $q_1\ldots q_n\tilde h_1\ldots \tilde h_n $ using the conjugations $h_iq_j=q_j\tilde h_i$.)

2. The group of isometries is $\mathrm {Iso}(\mathbb R ^2) = O(2) \ltimes \mathbb R^2$.
3. $O(2)=SO(2) \rtimes {\pm 1}$.

****Alternative formulation****
It is known that the group $\mathrm {Iso}(\mathbb R ^2) = O(2) \ltimes \mathbb R^2$ contains a free semigroup of order $2$. Why don't claims 1,2,3 disprove this?

Comment: What is your definition of group growth in this case: Your groups are not finitely generated; you should use Riemannian volume instead...

Comment: @Emolga I agree with [Moishe Kohan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84907/moishe-kohan). Or are you considering subgroups of $\text{Iso}(\mathbb R^2)$? In that cases which ones?

Comment: Added a definition. This is the definition which implies super-amenability.

Comment: I dont find the term "super-amenable group". Can you give a link? Also, do you have a link about the isometry group and amenability? You are saying it should not be amenable?

Comment: @DietrichBurde My false proof also "works" for the isometries of $\mathbb R^3$, which are not amenable, so it's not important to look up super-amenability, but I learned this from Choimet-Queffeléc ("Twelve Landmarks"), chapter 6.

Comment: In other words, your definition of subexponential growth is that every finitely generated subgroup has subexponential growth. Then the answer to your question is that your "proof" is not a proof. Try to write down all the relevant details to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that $\tilde h_i$ does not depend only on $h_i$, but also on $q_j$. (This is unlike the case of isometries of $\mathbb R^1$.) Thus the set of possible $\tilde h_i$ is no longer finite.